# How to get all column and type and internal name in my site by PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, modern-team-site, powershell-script

I'm using ModernUI for SharePoint Online.
I'd like to get all List and Library's ColumnName, Type, InternalName in my site by PnP PowerShell.
I did some research myself, but I didn't understand, so I would appreciate it if you could teach me how to do it.
Thank you for any information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1.[Download SharePoint Online Management Shell.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

2.Try below PowerShell as administrator.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
Function Get-SPOListFields()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ListName
    )
 
    Try {
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
         
        #Get the List
        $Lists = $Context.web.Lists
        $Context.Load($Lists)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
         
        #Array to hold result
        
        $FieldData = @()   
        ForEach($List in $Lists)
        {
          Foreach ($Field in $List.Fields)
         {  
            Write-Host $List.Title `t $Field.Title `t $Field.InternalName `t 
            $Field.TypeDisplayName
 
            #Send Data to object array
            $FieldData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    'List Title' = $List.Title
                    'Field Title' = $Field.Title                                       
                    'Internal Name' = $Field.InternalName
                    'Type' = $Field.TypeDisplayName
                    'Schema' = $Field.SchemaXML
                    }
          }
        }
        Return $FieldData
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Getting Fields from List!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
 
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="site collection URL"    
$CSVLocation ="local drive"
 
#Call the function to get all list fields
$FieldData | Export-Csv $CSVLocation -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works. But I'd like to do this for all List and Library. I don't want to specify a specific list. In that case, Do you have any script?

Comment: I have updated the PowerShell. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName -PnPManagementShell

$lists = Get-PnPList -Includes Fields

foreach($list in $lists)
{
    $list.Title
    $list.Fields | select title,internalname,typeasstring
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works very well. What if I want to output the list name as well?

Comment: Add `$list.Title` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I did like this `$list.Fields | select title,internalname,typeasstring,$list.Title`. But I got listname just one.